# Access vuex state data from template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have the following setup for my vuex state:

**store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import user from './modules/userAuth';
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules:{
    user
  }
})
```

**./store/modules/userAuth.js**

```js
const state = {
    isCustomer: false,
    isAdmin: false,
    userToken: null,
};

const getters = {
    //getter codes
    userData: (state) => state,
};

const actions = {
    async login({commit, dispatch}, data) {
        //login code
    },

    logout({commit}) {
        //logoutcode
    },

    autoLogout({dispatch}, milliseconds) {
        //auto logout code
    },
};
const mutations = {
    setForAdmin: (state, status) => (state.isAdmin = status),
    setForCustomer: (state, status) => (state.isCustomer = status),
    setUserToken: (state, token) => (state.token = token)
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
};
```

I can access access  actions like this:

```
import {mapActions} from "vuex";
  methods: {
...mapActions([
    "login",
    "logout",
    "autoLogout",
  "loadToken"
]),
```

But I cannot access state with `mapState` in my template:

```
import {mapState} from 'vuex';
computed: {...mapState(['userToken'])}
```

Although I can access the state data from this method `this.$store.state.user.userToken`

But that's too many characters to type. I've also tried `mapGetters` helper both of them giving undefinded on console.log

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
computed: mapGetters(["userData"]),
```

How do I access state data with `mapState` or `mapGetters`  helper

Comment: is your module namespaced?

Comment: Module namespace is `user`. Check first block of the code in the question.

Comment: Problem fixed.  Just restarted my express server and vue server and it's working. IDK what was wrong with Vue.